# Determine whether Q belongs to the ideal $<P1,P2>$

Tags: polynomials, ideals, minimal-polynomials

Q:= $x^{2}y+xy^{2}+y^{2}-2x-1$

$P_{1}=y^{2}-1$, $P_{2}=xy-1$.

Based on the previous questions we have been using the graded lexicographic order with $x>y$. So I have got the following:

$$x^{2}y+xy^{2}+y^{2}-2x-1 |  P_{1}: xy-1$$
$$xy^{2}-x+y^{2}-1| P_{2}: y^{2}-1$$
$$-x+y^{2}+y-1 | Q_{1}: x+y$$
$$y^{2}+y-1 | Q_{2} : 1 $$
$$ y | R: -x$$

Giving $Q=(xy-1)(x+y)+(y^{2}-1)(1)+(y-x)$, As the division algorithm has remainders and $P_{1},P_{2}$ do not divide the equation without remainder and I correct in saying that Q is not an ideal in $<P_{1},P_{2}>$

I have just begun learning about ideals on my course and want to ask if I am write in saying that Q does not belong to the ideal , although it does divide without remainder if I reverse $P_{1}, P_{2}$

Any help will be appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing $y^2$ and $xy$ by $1$, we get $$Q = x+x+1-2x-1=0 \mod \langle P_1,P_2 \rangle$$
, hence $Q \in \langle P_1,P_2 \rangle$.

Comment: why can we change $y^{2}$ and $xy$ by 1?

Comment: Because $y^2-1=0$ and $xy-1=0$...

Comment: wouldn't that only work is $P_{1}, P_{2}$ both equal 0. Can we assume this?

Comment: You should really recall what $R/I$ means, when $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal...By definition, $P_1=P_2=0$ in the quotient ring. When you work modulo an ideal generated by polynomials, this means nothing else but setting the generators of the ideal equal to zero.